# Assist me understand Intel XDK geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, intel-xdk

I'm trying to learn Intel XDK geolocation. I hope someone could be kind enough to teach me how to use geolocation. Please note that I have limited amount of knowledge in Javascript.

```
<script>
//I believe I should be creating variable here
var lat ="";
var long ='';

 //I understand this. event listener when the device is ready and if its ready call onDeviceReady function.

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

           //The on device ready function which I believe I can call the   geolocation method
    function onDeviceReady() {
    //my attempt to  get navigation. I have no Idea what should I do here
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                             [geolocationError],
                                             [geolocationOptions]);
    }       

    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
              'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
              'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
              'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
              'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
    };
        function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }           
</script>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing. Please assist me.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;-) It is hard to understand your problem if you yourself "have no idea what you're doing". This is not so much a site to get an introduction on how something works but to solve specific programming questions, but there is none here except that you would have to get some knowledge about what you're asking about, trying to to, and what problems you encounter -  and then to come back ask about them.

Comment: k k k k kk k kk kkk k k k